# "Not in a git repository" error in git-lfs

Tags: github, git-lfs

I have a over 100 mb csv file that i would like to upload to github using lfs. However, i am facing this issue (Screenshot added). I have put the csv file in the local folder where the repository is located.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH0a1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `init` a new repository or `clone` an existing repository first.

Answer (score 0):

The directory must have a `.git` folder to be able to run git commands. To create one, run `git init` and then you would be able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anybody have this problem inside a normal git repo, you probably have to add it to a safe directories:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory <your_repo_path>
```